# Simplenews is not Activated Automatically for Users

Tags: emails

I'm using [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) module for newsletters. My newsletter is set to subscribe users automatically on account creation. However the status remains inactivated after creation.

How can subscriptions be automatically activated?

Comment: Did you double check the permissions regarding simple news?

Comment: Yes I have checked it works only for automatic subscription there is no permission for changing the status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the ***silent*** option for new accounts, this only automatically activates if you've disabled email verification for new account registration or an admin activates the account (if requiring administrative approval).

[image]